# Inheritance Across Packages

Tags: java, inheritance

Let's say we have `package` `a` and `package` `b`, both have many classes, all `public`.

Now class `Cat` from `package` `a` wants to extend class `Animal` from `package` `b`, is this inheritance legal?

Comment: yes it is inheritance indeed

Comment: @Raj, just a note: edited the question so the classes' and packages' names follow the recommended naming convention.

Comment: Welcome to SO! FYI, you can simply write `a.Cat` to mean "class `Cat` from package `a`". This is very common Java syntax that anyone answering questions here on SO will understand.

Answer (score 2):

ASure, just import the parent class and extend it.

```
package a;

import b.Animal;

public class Cat extends Animal {

}
```

You can skip the import and use the fully qualified class name for Animal as well. But messier.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Packages make grouping classes convenient, and non-public and non-private methods and fields are only visible to other members of the same package